# jQuery Datatables - pre filter specific table column based on url value

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using jQuery Datatables, is it possible to search a specific column only on page load based on url value?

for example if the url ends with live, then filter the table column Is live (which is index 4 in this sample?)

```
url = "website.com/circuits/live"
if ("url ends with live"){ 
    $('#circuit_list').DataTable({
        column index 4 filter "Live"
     })
}
```

here is the table sample

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="circuit_list" role="grid" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>     
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Circuit</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Is Live</th>
        ...
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>EDIT</td>
        <td>DSL</td>
        <td>Liverpool</td>
        <td>Bills DSL</td>
        <td>Not Live</td>
        ...
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>EDIT</td>
        <td>DSL</td>
        <td>Manchester</td>
        <td>Bobs DSL</td>
        <td>Live</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showroom_list').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 30,
        responsive: true
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have RESTful url's as described in the question, then the easiest 
way to grab the last part is

```js
document.location.href.split('/').pop()
```

Now perform the search in the [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) callback:

```js
$('#circuit_list').DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    this
     .api()
     .column(4)
     .search( document.location.href.split('/').pop() )
     .draw()
  }
})
```

To perform an exact match search, i.e not include records containing "live" when the search term is "not live" turn "smart" search off, see [`column().search(input, regex, smart)`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()#Types) :

```
.search( document.location.href.split('/').pop(), false, false)
```

This can also be achieved by using a regular expression search :

```
.search( '^'+document.location.href.split('/').pop()+'$', true, false)
```

---

If you want a table wide search it is more convenient to simply use the [`search`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search) option :

```js
$('#circuit_list').DataTable({
  search: {
    search: document.location.href.split('/').pop()
  }
})
```

This have the advantage that the filter box automatically is populated with the search term as well.

Comment: I tested this one to learn about it and discovered a minor problem: in the example column 4 can be 'live' or 'not live'. The problem is that 'not live'  also contains the string 'live' so all columns are shown when using the example from the question.

Comment: Maybe the regex option could b the solution for that:  .search( "^Live$",true,false,false )  or .search( '^'+document.location.href.split('/').pop()+'$' )

Comment: @HansDash, have updated with two small additions. Yes, you can use regex but also just turn "smart" search off.

Comment: this is working perfectly using the regex option, however, would it be possible some text to the top of the table, that states its being filtered by Live sites and an link to clear the filter and set it back to normal?

Comment: perhaps inserting the text into the dataTables_length div next to the page num count?

Comment: @AlexW You could add an element to the `dom` attribute, perhaps like this `dom: 'l<"#url">frtip`' and then populate that with some info -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mevxotnm/** how you style it really depends on how the rest of the layout in your table is, perhaps you need to change float/display of `.dataTables_filter` and `.dataTables_length` so it fits in.

Answer (score 0):

Could you test this option, to lookup only into the 3rd column ?

```
$('#searchInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
  table
    .columns( 3 )
    .search( this.value )
    .draw();
});
```

As discribed in the documentation : https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Comment: didn't work,  looking at the source, the search field isnt name search input, it doesnt have an id. what I actually want is to take a value from the url, if the value matches Live then pre filter the table

Comment: Ive reworded the question to follow my specific query

Answer (score 0):

DataTables has a custom filtering capability.
    https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

So, I'd recommend you create a textbox above the jquery DIV that gets loaded with your query string parameter on page, and use the custom range filtering.

This is an example with a textbox with id of yourcustomfieldsid

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {

        var yourValue = $('#yourcustomfieldsid').val();
        var yourData = data[3];
        return yourData.indexOf(yourValue) >= 0;
    }
);
```

and getting the url parameters

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

and getting the textbox to the value from the URL

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#yourcustomfieldsid').val( getUrlVars()["querystringparametername"] );
});
```

You'll want an on change event when the textbox changes to refresh the table when the textbox changes.

```
$('#yourcustomfieldsid').change(function() {
    $('$jquerytableid').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

My apologies for any typos, but this should be the concept.